# Python reads incremental text

Tags: python

I saw a piece of code, as follows：

```
with open(‘text.txt’,‘r’)as fp:
  
    while True:
        data_line=fp.readline()

        if data_line:
            print(data_line)
```

writing data in txt，and all the time python will keep outputting.

I think this code is great.
But I don't quite understand the line `if data_line:`

I hope someone can explain it, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the code is checking if there is any value in the variable `data_line` and printing the value if the value is not `''` empty string.

Comment: I've never seen `fp.readline()` returning `None`. It may return an empty string though.

Comment: Thanks, You were correct. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

if data_line checks if any text was read:
if it is an empty string it will skip that section (the `print(data_line)`)